# Как получить название текущего месяца на русском?

Tags: java, android, calendar

```
mSelectMonth = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.select_month);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mSelectMonth.setText(calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH));
```

Так выводим на английском, а как сделать русский?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Использовать русскую локаль](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html) вместо английской:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String month = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH,
        Calendar.LONG_FORMAT, new Locale("ru"));
```

Вывод на экран:

> августа

---

Если нужны нестандартные названия месяцев, то придётся создать массив с ними:

```
String[] monthNames = { "Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь" };
String month = monthNames[calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)];
```

> Август

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы выводило не "Августа", а просто "Август"?

Comment: @msp это уже, скорее всего, придётся делать вручную - с помощью массива. Потому что предполагается, что при работе с датой используется название месяца в родительном падеже. Ещё в интернете пишут, что в старой версии Java 6 была проблема, что названия месяцев были в именительном падеже. Но искать и устанавливать старую версию Java, конечно, не вариант.

Answer (score 4):

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  String month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", new Locale("ru")).format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю свои 5 копеек:

> Использовать русскую локаль вместо английской

Не все Android аппараты поддерживают русскую локаль. Если требуется универсальная поддержка русской локали для всех аппаратов, то надо использовать либу [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org), которая цепляется через `LocaleServiceProvider`